# Printing repeated Django form fields individually

Tags: django-forms

I have a Django forms dilemma. When rendering a form in a template, I usually prefer to print the form fields individually, in stead of using the form.as_p annotation. However, in the form I am working on I have a set of fields that are repeated an unknown number of times. For example, if there are 3 items being edited the fields would be:

field_name_1 
field_email_1

field_name_2 
field_email_2

field_name_3 
field_email_3

But the number of items in not known to me beforehand. To solve this I am creating the fields in a loop in the **init** function, no problems there. But I can't figure out a way to print the fields individually in the template, since I don't know the whole name of each field. If this were my only problem I could just use the form.as_p syntax, no biggie. But I would also like to add some html to the beginning of each set of fields, so that the result would be:

**Add values 1:** 
field_name_1 
field_email_1

**Add values 2:** 
field_name_2 
field_email_2

**Add values 3:** 
field_name_3 
field_email_3

However, I haven't found a way to insert arbitrary html into a form in Django code, similar to #markup in Drupal forms. So:

1. Is there a way to print the fields individually so I can put the extra html in the template? (What I am missing here is the exact syntax)
2. If not, how do I insert the extra html into the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this in the template?:

```
{% for field in form %}
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ field.errors }}
    {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

(from the Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#looping-over-hidden-and-visible-fields )

You could render the header with something like:
Add values {{forloop.counter}}: